# Order of the pole of $f(z)=\frac{\log (1+z)}{z^3}$ at $z=0$ .

Tags: complex-analysis

What is the order of the pole at $z=0$ of the function

$$f(z)=\frac{\log (1+z)}{z^3}$$

I have developed the logarithm function in a series:

$$\frac{\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}n z^n}{z^3}$$

and then, I came to the conclusion that the pole is of second order. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Yes, the reasoning is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, indeed! Since $$f(z)=\frac1{z^2}-\frac1{2z}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k+3}z^k,$$ then it has a pole of order $2$ at $z=0.$